# Data Returns Null even though snapshot has data, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm calling an API and the return data says that it is not empty yet my `FutureBuilder` returns null value. When I print out the response.body it says : `{"statusCode":200,"message":"Success"}`, so I'm not sure if the API is wrong or is it something else?

API call:

```
Future<UserData> getUser() async {
    final response =
        await APIRequest(Method.GET, '/users/' + this._loggedUserEmail);
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return UserData(
        name: jsonDecodedResponse['name'],
        surname: jsonDecodedResponse['surname'],
        email: jsonDecodedResponse['email'],
        phoneMobile: jsonDecodedResponse['phoneMobile'],
        address: jsonDecodedResponse['address'],
        dateCreated: jsonDecodedResponse['dateCreated'],
        dateModified: jsonDecodedResponse['dateModified']);
  }
```

User model:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class UserData extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String dateCreated,
      dateModified,
      name,
      surname,
      email,
      phoneMobile,
      address;

  UserData({
    this.dateCreated,
    this.dateModified,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.surname,
    this.phoneMobile,
    this.address,
  });

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserData(
      dateCreated: json['dateCreated'],
      dateModified: json['dateModified'],
      name: json['name'],
      surname: json['surname'],
      email: json['email'],
      phoneMobile: json['phoneMobile'],
      address: json['address'],
    );
  }
}
```

The Future builder:

```
Future<UserData> _getUserValues() async {
    final _userData = await APIcalls.instance.getUser();
    return _userData;
  }

.....

FutureBuilder<UserData>(
      future: _getUserValues(), // async work
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data.email}'); // returns null
        }
      },
    );
```

Am I parsing the JSON data (again), or something else is wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: add your api result data sample or model !

Comment: is it that when connectionState.waiting != connectionState.hasData ?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi added the user model.

Comment: @Ced the state goes into the `connectionState.waiting` then when the API data returns, the `Result: null` is returned like I stated above.

Comment: there is a hasData property / method on the connectionState. Your email in your response might be null

Comment: does other than email prints data ?